# syncing reminders with due date in the reminder app into the calendar app in catalina?

Tags: macos, calendar, reminders

I was wondering if it was possible to have reminders with dates in my reminder app to also appear on the calendar app?

Comment: Are you interested in third-party software recommendations, or only using the software built into macOS?

Comment: Is this for iOS or macOS?  What versions?  What have you tried already?  See [ask] for tips on asking questions.

Comment: @Nic preferably software built into macOS, but third party will do fine too.

Comment: @fsb for macOS. version 10.15.3. I tried to look into the settings of the app.